# Booting kernel (FIT image) with no rootfs

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, ram, initrd

An embedded Linux device I am working with has the following kernel parameter:

`root=/dev/ram0`

Additionally, the kernel image is bundled together with an initrd and device tree to make a *flattened image tree*, or [FIT](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkimage) image.

When fully booted the device does not have persistent storage. That is, anything written to the file system is completely volatile. Considering the `root=` parameter passed to the kernel, this is not surprising.

My questions is: How does this work?

- I do know that Uboot copies the kernel into ram and executes it with a `bootm` command, but where do the filesystem files come from? Are they contained within the initrd? My understanding of an initrd is that it is a temporary construct. If so, it would be an offset into FIT image blob. So, how is just passing `root=/dev/ram0` sufficient for the kernel to know where its file system is?
- Does the kernel perform introspection and read the FIT image's header to determine placement of constituent components?
- How are file system changes supported inside a FIT image considering it will be packed together with both the kernel and device tree blob?

Answer (score 0):

> I do know that Uboot copies the kernel into ram and executes it with a bootm command, but where do the filesystem files come from?

Before you can boot your fitImage you have to load it into RAM. After this you can start it with `bootm`. Inside the fit image you can define the `Load Address` and `Entry Point` for the kernel for example.

> Are they contained within the initrd? My understanding of an initrd is that it is a temporary construct. If so, it would be an offset into FIT image blob. So, how is just passing root=/dev/ram0 sufficient for the kernel to know where its file system is?

It depends on your system what the definition of filesystem is. There are a few systems running completely from a RAMDISK and just storing configuration into any kind of [NVRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory) or Flash.

Other systems use the RAMDisk to check where to find the root filesystem. For example to scan USB-Bus, SATA or SD-Cards. When the root filesystem is mounted the boot process continuous with this partition. Due to the fact that init needs to run from PID 1. Some [tricks are needed](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/AN2008_05_ChangingYourRoots).

> Does the kernel perform introspection and read the FIT image's header to determine placement of constituent components?

No the fitImage is parsed by u-boot. How the u-boot passes the addresses where the DTB and RAMDISK is located at depends on the used Platform AFAIK.

> How are file system changes supported inside a FIT image considering it will be packed together with both the kernel and device tree blob?

When changes to the filesystems are needed on a regular basis you should consider to use something more flexible. But this depends on the hardware you are using. SD-Card, NAND, NOR or spinning disks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the kernel source code:

- `mtdsplit_fit.c`

  ```
      /* Search for the rootfs partition after the FIT image */
      ret = mtd_find_rootfs_from(mtd, fit_offset + fit_size, mtd->size,
                                 &rootfs_offset, NULL);
      if (ret) {
              pr_info("no rootfs found after FIT image in \"%s\"\n",
                      mtd->name);
              return ret;
      }
  ```
- `mtdsplit.c`:

  ```
  int mtd_find_rootfs_from(struct mtd_info *mtd,
                           size_t from,
                           size_t limit,
                           size_t *ret_offset,
                           enum mtdsplit_part_type *type)
  {
          size_t offset;
          int err;

          for (offset = from; offset < limit;
               offset = mtd_next_eb(mtd, offset)) {
                  err = mtd_check_rootfs_magic(mtd, offset, type);
                  if (err)
                          continue;

                  *ret_offset = offset;
                  return 0;
          }

          return -ENODEV;
  }
  EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(mtd_find_rootfs_from);



  int mtd_check_rootfs_magic(struct mtd_info *mtd, size_t offset,
                             enum mtdsplit_part_type *type)
  {
          u32 magic;
          size_t retlen;
          int ret;

          ret = mtd_read(mtd, offset, sizeof(magic), &retlen,
                         (unsigned char *) &magic);
          if (ret)
                  return ret;

          if (retlen != sizeof(magic))
                  return -EIO;

          if (le32_to_cpu(magic) == SQUASHFS_MAGIC) {
                  if (type)
                          *type = MTDSPLIT_PART_TYPE_SQUASHFS;
                  return 0;
          } else if (magic == 0x19852003) {
                  if (type)
                          *type = MTDSPLIT_PART_TYPE_JFFS2;
                  return 0;
          } else if (be32_to_cpu(magic) == UBI_EC_MAGIC) {
                  if (type)
                          *type = MTDSPLIT_PART_TYPE_UBI;
                  return 0;
          }

          return -EINVAL;
  }
  EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(mtd_check_rootfs_magic);
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, simply showing the relevant source code does not really _explain_ how the FIT boot process works ...